# Optional function prop in React component Flow type check fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am using React's PropTypes and Flow type checker but I am having trouble getting an optional function prop to pass the type check. Here is an example:

```
var Example = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    exampleFn: React.PropTypes.func
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    if (this.props.exampleFn) {
      this.props.exampleFn();
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return <a onClick={this.handleClick}>Click here</a>;
  }
});
```

Although I'm checking `this.props.exampleFn` is not null, running Flow's type checker against this code gives me the error

```
call of method exampleFn
Function cannot be called on possibly null or undefined value
```

I've tried different variations such as
 
`if (this.props.exampleFn !== null && this.props.exampleFn !== undefined) {...}`
or
`this.props.exampleFn && this.props.exampleFn()`
etc. to know that we're guarding against a possibly null/undefined value but I can't find anything that works. Of course, changing the prop type to `React.PropTypes.func.isRequired` results in no errors but I'd like to keep this prop optional.

How can I get an optional function prop to pass the type check?

Comment: does `if (this.props.exampleFn != null)` work ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way we've found to keep the PropType optional but still have the Flow type check pass.

```
...

handleClick: function() {
  var exampleFn = this.props.exampleFn || null;
  if (exampleFn) {
    exampleFn();
  }
},

...
```